# How to store video files in android without exposing raw files to the users?

Tags: android, video-streaming, virtual-reality

I am developing a VR Application using [Google VR SDK](https://developers.google.com/vr/concepts/vrview).Due to nature of app users very frequently play same video in a day.Using the code below i play videos from URL and this consumes so much bandwidth

I want to decrease bandwidth usage.I think i can store videos in phone memory so next time they play it can simply be played from memory but in this case users would easily access my files and steal it

So is there a way to do this (like some kind of cache) but without simply exposing users to my raw video files?

```
 class VideoLoaderTask extends AsyncTask<Pair<Uri, Options>, Void, Boolean> {
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Pair<Uri, Options>... fileInformation) {
        try {

                Options options = new Options();
                options.inputFormat= Options.FORMAT_DEFAULT;
                options.inputType = Options.TYPE_MONO;
                Uri myUri = Uri.parse("video.mp4");
                videoWidgetView.loadVideo(myUri, options);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // An error here is normally due to being unable to locate the file.
            loadVideoStatus = LOAD_VIDEO_STATUS_ERROR;
            // Since this is a background thread, we need to switch to the main thread to show a toast.
            videoWidgetView.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast
                            .makeText(SimpleVrVideoActivity.this, "Error opening file. ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                }
            });
            Log.e(TAG, "Could not open video: " + e);
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you think transmitting them over HTTP is safer? This can also be eavesdroped. HTTPS will require more effort, but unless you roll out very strict HTTPS checks, this can be also circumvented.

Comment: Because basic users don't know how to eavesdrop stream over HTTP.Video files are not FBI secret but i still don't want them to stay as raw video file in user sd card.Thanks for the advice thought maybe i will use HTTPS in future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution in [developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal).I can simply just save files to the storage

```
String FILENAME = "hello_file";
String string = "hello world!";

FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
//Context.MODE_PRIVATE makes them invisible to users
fos.write(string.getBytes());
fos.close();
```